# Pushing logs to Log Analytics from Databricks

Tags: azure-log-analytics, azure-databricks

I have logs collected in Databricks cluster but I need to pushed to Log Analytics in Azure to have a common log collection

Have not tried anything but would like to know what the approach

Comment: Sorry, but what is it that you need? To know how to push logs to Databricks?

Answer (score -1):

To know how to push databricks logs to Azure Log Analytics.